# PHP Unable to load superclass if I extends in subclass on linux server

Tags: php

If put my php project In linux server I got an error to load superclass if I extends in subclass (NO with win s.o)

```
Fatal error: Class 'Upload' not found in /home/www/class/class.photos.php on line xx
```

In my index.php I've this code to load classes dinamically

```
<?php
function __autoload($class_name) {
    if(file_exists('class/class.' . strtolower($class_name) . '.php')) {
        require_once('class/class.' . strtolower($class_name) . '.php'); 
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Unable to load $class_name.");
    }
}

other class..

$ph = new Photos($db);

?>
```

In my class dir I've class.photos.php , class.upload.php and other classes

This is my subclass class.photos.php

```
class Photos extends Upload {

    something

}
```

I tried also to instantiate the superclass upload in index.php, but with no success.

How could I solve this issue? thanks

Comment: You should check case of the file name. On Linux "class.upload.php" and "class.Upload.php" are different.

Comment: case sensitive issue?

Comment: Can you put in more code? How r u passing `$class_name` and where ? As @chumkiu and @Dharmesh pointed out, it could be case sensitive issue. Your `__autoload` function might not be working.

Comment: @Maz The argument passed to `__autoload` is automatically done by PHP when it cannot resolve a symbol (class) name. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: I'd prefix those file paths with `__DIR__`, eg `__DIR__ . '/class/class.' ...`. PHP can get a bit funny around which is the current working directory.

Comment: I use strtolower function for case sensitive iusse. This happens only when I extends the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the fatal error including upload superclass at the beginnig of the subclass file

class.photos.php

```
require_once('class.' . strtolower('Upload') . '.php');

class Photos extends Upload {

}
```

I hope it's correct.